# SQL Replace function using CharIndex Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select REPLACE(comments,substring(comments, 
charindex('statement',comments), LEN(comments)),'') 
from Customer 
where charindex('statement',comments) <>0
```

I want to replace only "statement" from column comments using Replace function but it replaces records to ' ' which doesn't have "Statement" string in it.

Answer (score 3):

Pls try like this, this will only replace the string statement from the comments :

```
declare @Customer table(comments nvarchar(max))
insert into @Customer values('this is a statement'), ('statement is this'), ('this')


select case when charindex('statement',comments) <> 0 then REPLACE(comments,substring(comments, charindex('statement',comments), LEN('statement')),'')
else comments end from @Customer 

select * from @Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change that to use `>` greater than comparison

```
where charindex('statement',comments) > 0
```

(OR) Use like operator

```
where comments like '%statement%'
```

Comment: Yes I tried both of them but it still updates records to ' ' which do not contain string 'Statement' in it

Comment: @DipenShah, post sample data where `statement` not present and it does the update still.